# What Keyboard shortcuts should not use?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I almost developed  a C# Winforms application. Now I'm looking to provide some keyboard shortcuts to the user for some operations. I want to know that what keyboard shortcuts I should not use that are reserved for windows.

Also tell me what is the preferred key between <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> for the shortcuts?

For example - if I want to add a new employee: what key shortcut should I use? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Comment: For "new employee", I'd new `Ctrl-N` which is the key for "New <something>" in most other apps I know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For windows specifically you can look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) for all the windows shortcuts.
Just to be sure you can also look at this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts)
The preference for "Alt" over "Ctrl" or the other way around is only what you think is more usable and more user friendly. I would suggest that you think of other keys as well such as "Shift" and F keys.

Comment: This is pretty good answer.
But as`CTRL+C` is use for `COPY`. So If I use `CTRL+C` in my application to Add `New Customer`. Will it work ??

Comment: Technically you can override CTRL+C for your app, it depends how you try to catch the input. You can add shortcuts to the registry, please note that this override them for all of windows, if you just catch the user input in your app then you will get Copy and the new functionality you add.
I would not recommend overloading CTRL+C since this is very widely used.

Answer (score 2):

Any key combination except for those that are used by windows by default like Alt + F4. Because this shortcut is used to close the window. And also shortcuts like Alt + Tab shouldnt be used as they are Windows default shortcuts. Other than such window shortcuts, you can choose any fancy combinations that you prefer as a shortcut to your application. All the best. Hope this helps.